# Add Full Populated Object to another Schema object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save my full (populated products) cart in my purchases. But I am still getting product Ids in my purchases but not whole populated product from that cart.

This is the purchases -> cart-> product, should be populated full object but I am getting only Object Ids of products in the database.

[image]

The Population query is like this.

```
Cart.findOne({ userId }).populate("products.id").exec()
```

And then I am saving full cart object like this in my purchases

[image]

and its type is Object in my schema

[image]

Even I am getting full object in the response but it is not saving in the database.

[image]

So why not in database?

Comment: why do you want to store the entire referenced document, it simply increases the document size and will cause issues while updating it, better to store id(s) and populate later

Comment: I am storing full object because I am not updating ever there. It will stored forever. it's just like keeping the history.